# C++ operator < overloading

Tags: c++, sorting, operators

I have a problem with overloading of the < operator.
I have this class:

WordEntry.h:

```
class WordEntry
{
public:
    WordEntry(string word);
    ~WordEntry();

    bool operator<(const WordEntry otherWordEntry);

    string getWord();

private:
    string _word;
};
```

WordEntry.cpp(I removed constructor & destructor):

```
string WordEntry::getWord()
{
   return _word;
}


bool WordEntry::operator<(WordEntry otherWordEntry)
{
   return  lexicographical_compare(_word.begin(),_word.end(),otherWordEntry.getWord().begin(),otherWordEntry.getWord().end());
}
```

Everything is fine when I'm using it in main.cpp like that:

```
    WordEntry w1("Der");
    WordEntry w2("das");

    if (w1.operator<(w2)) {
       cout << "w1 > w2";
    }
    else 
    {
       cout << "w2 > w1";
    }
```

But when I call `sort()` on a `vector` with `WordEntry` objects, I'll get the error message

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('const WordEntry' and 'const
>   WordEntry')

and it points to `stl_algo.h`.

Does anyone knows what's going on here?

Comment: `const` copy pretty much defeats the purpose ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now the argument to `<` is const but the member is not.  This means a `<` comparison between 2 `const WordEntry&` objects will fail because it can't bind to `<`.  You need to make the member and the argument both `const`

```
bool operator<(const WordEntry& otherWordEntry) const;

bool WordEntry::operator<(const WordEntry& otherWordEntry) const {
  ...
}
```

Note: As pointed out in the comments you should also pass `WordEntry` by reference

Comment: @LeonS: Note that your code still has undefined behavior. While it might seem to work you might also find that the application sometimes crashes if you compare one string with a substring, like "Hello" and "Hell" in the right order (`WordEntry("Hello").operator<(WordEntry("Hell"))`)

Answer (score 2):

Use a const reference for the rvalue and make the method const to promise the compiler you won't change the object.

```
bool operator<(const WordEntry& otherWordEntry) const
{
    // comparison
}
```

You also don't need to explicitly call the operator.
Once defined for the `WordEntry` object you can do this:

```
if (w1 < w2) { // etc }
```

Since you aren't using a custom comparing predicate you could just use the `std::string::operator<`:

```
return _word < otherWordEntry._word;
```

David makes an excellent point on returning the internal member by value. If you want to use `lexicographical_compare` with an accessor instead of the `_word` member directly (which can as you're in the class scope) then you should define it like so:

```
const string& getWord() const { return _word; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string WordEntry::getWord()
bool WordEntry::operator<(WordEntry otherWordEntry)
{
   return  lexicographical_compare(_word.begin(),
                                   _word.end(),
                                   otherWordEntry.getWord().begin(),
                                   otherWordEntry.getWord().end());
}
```

The `getWord` member function creates a copy of the internal member attribute and returns the copy. Two consecutive calls to `getWord` will return two different `std::string` instances with the same contents, but they are different objects none the less. The `lexicographical_compare` function requires that the first and second arguments are iterators into the same container, and similarly the third and fourth arguments. In your case you are passing iterators into **different** containers (string), which will be compared inside the function and will yield undefined behavior.

The simplest solution is have `getWord` return a `const` reference to the internal `std::string`, in that way, the iterators will both refer to the internal object in the right hand side object.

As others have also mentioned, you should pass the `WordEntry` by `const` reference, and the `operator<` should be `const`, to *improve* the code. But the issue in your implementation is the mixture of iterators from different container.